Cypress and NextJS using React Server Actions
I'm trying to intercept the client side request that's done by React Server Components for my tests in Cypress.
I thought it should be as simple as looking at and copying the request response (including headers) in the network tab and copy that to Cypress' intercept function, but I keep getting the error Connection closed and the request result in my front end code logs undefined.
Any ideas?
My current intercept implementation in my Cypress test:
cy.intercept("POST", "/account/register", {
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: {
    "x-action-revalidated": "[[],0,0]",
    "content-type": "text/x-component",
  },
  body: `0:["$@1",["development",null]]\n1:{"result":"success","status":200,"data":{"id":"91ffe221-ace9-40a1-98d5-2851cb071cbd","name":"Test User","email":"test@test.com","createdAt":"$D2024-05-26T16:32:11.280Z","updatedAt":"$D2024-05-26T14:32:11.288Z"}}`,
}).as("registerRequest");

The error message in my console:
index-3fe21bb9.js:133640 Error: The following error originated from your application code, not from Cypress. It was caused by an unhandled promise rejection.

  > Connection closed.

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your application it will automatically fail the current test.

This behavior is configurable, and you can choose to turn this off by listening to the `uncaught:exception` event.
    at close (webpack-internal:///app-pages-browser/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2131:31)
    at progress (webpack-internal:///app-pages-browser/./node_modules/next/dist/compiled/react-server-dom-webpack/cjs/react-server-dom-webpack-client.browser.development.js:2148:7)
From previous event:
    at Promise.longStackTracesCaptureStackTrace [as _captureStackTrace] (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:3486:19)
    at Promise._then (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:1239:17)
    at Promise._passThrough (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:4110:17)
    at Promise.lastly.Promise.finally (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:4119:17)
    at Object.onRunnableRun (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:162793:53)
    at $Cypress.action (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:41042:28)
    at Runnable.run (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:145381:13)
    at Runner.runTest (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:155323:10)
    at http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:155449:12
    at next (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:155232:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:155242:7
    at next (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:155144:14)
    at http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:155210:5
    at timeslice (http://localhost:3000/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:145721:27)


Any updates on this. Ran into this today. The state coming back from the server action just isn't being set

is it possible to provide a simple working code example? maybe on github or something

I see from documentation Server Components allow you to move data fetching to the server so is it actually a client-side request? Might explain Connection closed message.

Ok, so reading further "POST" fetches are always client-side.

I've figured it out. There are two things to note when intercepting and returning a custom response for a React Server Action request:

Make sure the header Content-Type: "text/x-component" is present on the response
Make sure the response body has a new line on the end of the content

The second one is what I was missing.
This example interception does work:
cy.intercept("POST", "/account/register", {
  headers: {
    "content-type": "text/x-component",
  },
  body: `0:["$@1",["development",null]]\n1:{"result":"success","status":200,"data":{"id":"982310j2","name":"Test User","email":"test@test.com","createdAt":"$D2024-05-26T16:32:11.280Z","updatedAt":"$D2024-05-26T14:32:11.288Z"}}\n`,
}).as("registerRequest");

I published a repository example cypress test using React Server Actions, so if anyone still has problems with mocking the response of a server action in cypress, they can look at my implementation here: https://github.com/terrabythia/cypress-server-action-test-example

Are you sure text/x-component comes from a server action and not a server component? They are different things.

Yes I'm sure. Every server action response header contains the value text/x-component for the property content-type.

Gotcha, thanks for confirming.

Is the Content-Type supposed to be "text/component" or "text/x-compoents"? also preemptive THANKS!

The snippet is correct and it should work as-is, so text/component. Good luck! :)

This worked Thanks! And to be clear the snippet says text/x-component not text/component. You have to have it as text/x-component for it to work.
Your snippet above is correct but the first bullet point in your write up is not.
Thanks so much! I spent a couple of hours on this the other day with another SE and the thing we were missing was the newline at the end.
Also I didn't try the snippet but rather the example in your repo at https://github.com/terrabythia/cypress-server-action-test-example/blob/main/cypress/e2e/server-action.cy.js which is slightly different

@DrewLandgrave @morganney Yes, sorry. I was wrong! It's text/x-component not text/component. I cannot edit my comment 3 comments above, but I've changed it in my answer. Sorry for the confusion. The snippet and the code in the example repository were already correct.

I handle server actions by updating parameters in my URL. Each server action should have a unique identifier. When an action is called, it should be added to the URL as a parameter and removed once the server action is completed (whether it succeeds or fails). This ensures that each server action is called with a unique identifier, making it easier to intercept.
This approach will add extra logic to your server actions and application.
Here is an example of the code:
React component:
"use client"

import React, { useState } from 'react'

import { getData } from '@/actions/getData.action';

const addParamToUrl = (param: string, value: string) => {
  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  if (value) {
    url.searchParams.set(param, value);
  } else {
    url.searchParams.delete(param);
  }
  window.history.pushState({}, '', url);
}

const Button = () => {
  
   const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
   const [data, setData] = useState<string | null>(null);
   const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const handleGetData = async (identifier: string, wrong?: boolean) => {
    setLoading(true);
    
    addParamToUrl("identifier", identifier);
    const data = await getData(identifier, wrong);
    addParamToUrl("identifier", "");

   if(data?.error) {    
    setError("Error fetching data");
   } else {
    setData(data?.data);
   }
    setLoading(false);
  }
  
 
  return (
    <>
        <button 
          className='bg-green-500 cursor-pointer p-5 rounded-md' 
          data-cy="success"
          onClick={() => handleGetData("successIdentifier")}
        >
          Success message
        </button>
        <button 
          className='bg-red-500 cursor-pointer p-5 rounded-md' 
          data-cy="error"
          onClick={() => handleGetData("errorIdentifier", true)}
        >
          Error message
        </button>
        <div className='flex items-center justify-center flex-col'>
            {JSON.stringify(data)}
            {loading && <div>Loading...</div>}
            {error && <div className='text-red-500'>{error}</div>}
        </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Button

Cypress test:
describe("template spec", () => {
  it("Click Success and r", async() => {
    cy.visit("http://localhost:3000");
    cy.intercept("POST", "http://localhost:3000/?identifier=successIdentifier")
.as("successHandler");
    cy.intercept("POST", "http://localhost:3000/?identifier=errorIdentifier")
.as("errorHandler");

    cy.get('[data-cy="success"]').click();
    cy.get('[data-cy="error"]').click();
    
    cy.wait("@successHandler").then(() => {
      cy.log("successHandler intercepted");
    });
    
    cy.wait("@errorHandler").then(() => {
      cy.log("errorHandler intercepted");
    });
  });
});

Server action:
'use server'
 
const delay = (time: number): Promise<void> => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
        resolve();
       }, time);
  });
}

export async function getData(identifier: string, wrong?: boolean) {
   try {
    await delay(Math.random() * 10000);
    if(wrong){
        throw new Error("Error fetching data");
    }
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`)
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(identifier);
    return {
        data
    }
   } catch {
     return {
        error: "Error fetching data",
     }
   }
}

